# Abrir form em MDI e fechar uma quando abrir outra?

Tags: c#

A minha duvida é, como faço para abrir um *form* em uma MDI e depois que abrir outro o anterior se feche ou simplesmente suma do MDI.

**sei que esse não é o certo mais vai dar pra entender o que eu quero!**

```cs
  Form Consulta = new frmConsulta();
            if (Consulta.Show == true) //Se consulta estiver aberto e apenas oculto
            {
                Consulta.Hide(); //então apareça
            }
            else// se não
            {
                Consulta.Show();// abra
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer isso você pode utilizar a propriedade [OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.90).aspx), que é um coleção com os formulários abertos, segue um exemplo de como utilizar:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
{
    public frmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FecharFormulariosFilhos()
    {
        // percorre todos os formulários abertos
        for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // se o formulário for filho
            if (Application.OpenForms[i].IsMdiChild)
            {
                // fecha o formulário
                Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnFilho1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FecharFormulariosFilhos();

        // cria a exibe o formulário filho
        frmFilho1 frmFilho = new frmFilho1();
        frmFilho.MdiParent = this;
        frmFilho.Show();
    }

    private void btnFilho2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FecharFormulariosFilhos();

        // cria a exibe o formulário filho
        frmFilho2 frmFilho = new frmFilho2();
        frmFilho.MdiParent = this;
        frmFilho.Show();
    }
}
```

Utilizei a propriedade `IsMdiChild` como parâmetro para verificar quais formulários deveriam ser fechados, porém você pode utilizar outras, por exemplo `Name` ou `Text`.

> **Nota:** o `frmPrincipal` (formulário pai) também está na coleção.

O motivo de eu ter utilizar um `for` regressivo e não um `foreach` ou um `for` normal, é porquê daria um erro, conforme discutido nessa pergunta [Close all open forms except the main menu in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029351/close-all-open-forms-except-the-main-menu-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Brigadão cara...ajudou muito!!

Comment: @Mateus, boa resposta

Comment: Me ajudou muito.. Obrigado